# Angular 6 child routes not working

Tags: angular, html, typescript, angular-routing

I have a simple navigation for angular 6 app , I am trying to make routing and child routing work in a simple configuration, but unfortunately I can not seem to make it work.

Here is the structure of my app

```
└───src
    ├───app
    │   ├───components
    │   │   ├───about
    │   │   ├───clients
    │   │   ├───footer
    │   │   ├───how-it-wo
    │   │   ├───partners
    │   │   ├───projects
    │   │   ├───team
    │   │   ├───whatwedo
    │   │   └───why-choos
    │   ├───layout
    │   │   └───main-layo
    │   └───shared
    ├───assets
    │   ├───charts
    │   ├───css
    │   ├───fonts
    │   ├───icon
    │   └───images
    └───environments
```

Here is the routing, `app.routing.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { MainLayoutComponent } from './layout/main-layout/main-layout.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './components/about/about.component';
import { WhatwedoComponent } from './components/whatwedo/whatwedo.component';
import { ProjectsComponent } from './components/projects/projects.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './components/footer/footer.component';
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: MainLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'about',
        component: AboutComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'what',
        component: WhatwedoComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'projects',
        component: ProjectsComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'contacts',
        component: FooterComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
  ],
  declarations: [],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Here is the html

```
<nav class="main-nav">
    <ul class="main-nav__list " ng-sticky [addClass]="'main-sticky-link'" [ngClass]="ref.click === true? 'Navbar__ToggleShow' :''">
          <li class="main-nav__item" routerLinkActive="active">
            <a class="main-nav__link" routerLink="/">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="main-nav__item" routerLinkActive="active">
            <a class="main-nav__link" routerLink="/home/about">About us</a>
          </li>
          <li class="main-nav__item" routerLinkActive="active">
            <a class="main-nav__link" routerLink="/home/what">What we do</a>
          </li>
          <li class="main-nav__item" routerLinkActive="active">
            <a class="main-nav__link" routerLink="/home/projects">Projects</a>
          </li>
          <li class="main-nav__item" routerLinkActive="active">
            <a class="main-nav__link" routerLink="/home/contacts">Contacts</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
</nav>
<div class="majeni-app">
  <app-whatwedo></app-whatwedo>
  <app-about></app-about>
  <app-projects></app-projects>
  <app-why-choose-us></app-why-choose-us>
  <app-team></app-team>
  <app-footer></app-footer>
</div>
```

**UPDATE** here is the gitbuh repo for reference
https://github.com/gruby-murzyn/agency/tree/master/majeni

when I click eg about us  nothing is happening but the url on browser loooks okay

`http://localhost:4200/home/about`

what am I doing wrong in my codes?

Comment: @Nico here is the link to github https://github.com/gruby-murzyn/agency/tree/master/majeni

Comment: where is `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` ? try adding it in html

Comment: in app.component.html , here is the link to the app in github https://github.com/gruby-murzyn/agency/tree/master/majeni

Comment: You have wrong import in app.module.ts use `import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';` instead of import { AppRoutingModule } from './/app-routing.module';

Comment: @alt255 bro appRouting is imported automatically using angular cli, when generated using `ng g module app routing`, so that is not the problem, even removing what u suggested does not solve the problem

Answer (score 58, accepted):

When you use `children` inside of your routes the parent component needs to have `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` inside it's html in order for the children to be loaded inside that parent. [Angular Docs on Child Configuration](https://angular.io/guide/router#child-route-configuration)

Additionally, with *routed* components it is not necessary to add the component selector inside the html of the parent component as they will be injected automatically by the router below your `router-outlet`.

So you in your case change your 
last div to show:

```
<div class="majeni-app">
 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
<!-- All children will be inserted here -->
  <app-footer></app-footer>
</div>
```

Or selectors you had inside of your html are not routed components and *should be shown on each child*
then simply add the `router-outlet` to the specific location

```
<div class="majeni-app">
  <app-whatwedo></app-whatwedo>
  <app-about></app-about>
  <app-projects></app-projects>
  <app-why-choose-us></app-why-choose-us>
  <app-team></app-team>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <!-- All children will be loaded here -->
  <app-footer></app-footer>
</div>
```

Comment: your right bro as you can see your method displays only header and footer,  , but I want everything to be displayed when the app is live and when user click about us or our poject or contacts , should just scroll down to about us section or projects or contacts etc, is it possible to achieve that? if so how?

Comment: after you have edited your answer,  everything is loaded , but when I click eg about us , the page does not scroll down to about us section, is it possible to achieve that?

Comment: what happens when you navigate to any page? does it scroll to the top or does the scroll position remain the same?

Comment: does nothing bro, I want something like this http://angular-landing.mhrafi.com/home/one   try click any nav link you will see what happen

Comment: I think you need to look into using fragments if you want them to be controlled by the router.
Where a Fragment refer to certain elements on the page identified with an id attribute.
 https://angular.io/guide/router#query-parameters-and-fragments

Comment: Thanks  bro, I will try using Id and scrollto get what I want

Comment: I'm not sure why I missed this detail, but I NEVER knew that the output of a child route had to go IN the parent component.  This is the first time I've seen it actually explained.  Makes perfect sense though!

Comment: Thank you very much !!
Same like my friend just above me : I've been stuck for like 2 hours trying to figure out what was the issue with my child routes..
Thank you very much that's a time saving !
(And it was actually written in the official documentation of Angular... Just checked it)

Comment: Adding a <router-outlet></router-outlet> inside my Player module added my Player Import/Export/Data modules. Just like black magic. Thanks.